# Oracle Forms DB Password

Tags: oracle10g, oracleforms

Using Oracle Form editor, once DB password are changed where to change the password in the form (.fmb) files. Tried to search "logon" command in the code but cant able to find. 
So since the password is changed every time it is requesting to provide the DB password when the form is accessed from browser.

Comment: Forms doesn't save the password anywhere - this is something custom rolled in your case.

Comment: Thanks @Sathya for info